# Customizing new-window placement

Tags: macos, window-manager

Is there any way for a user to customize how OSX chooses where to place new windows?  It would be great if I could create rules for how that's done, especially if I could do it per-application.

To be more explicit, when I open a new window of any application in OSX, the normal window manager places the window in a particular location on the screen.  I know that the application has at least some control over that placement, but I want to know if I, as a user, can specify the location geometry for a new window.

As comparison, in X11 applications, you can specify a `-geom` option.  What I'm looking for here is the equivalent, although I was hoping for a utility that could make (what I would see as) better decisions than what the standard OSX window manager is choosing.

(I'm using 10.7.4, but I would hope that this would be something that would be more universal.)

Comment: You mean, choose which "Desktop" a window opens up into? By the way, what version of OS X are you running?

Comment: No.  I added some additional information in the hopes of more clearly explaining myself.